# invoke method via returned ref from "can"

Tags: perl

Normally, to call a method from its reference, it should go something like below:

```
$methodref->(@args)
```

But when invoke a method from its reference returned from "can", it seems inconsistent.

```
$methodref = $my_obj->can(my_method);
$my_obj->$methodref(@args) if $methodref; # why it isn't $my_obj->$methodref->(@args)?
```

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks,
CC

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the object has to be the first thing passed in to the function.  This is automatically done for you if you make a method call.  But `$methodref->($my_obj, @args)` will also work.

Answer (score 2):

The CODE ref returned by `can` doesn’t have an object associated with it once that `can` is done. That’s why you still need to use an object as an invocant.

Note that this is dangerous, because there is no longer any guarantee that this is method that is supposed to be called on that object.  I suppose you might do something like this:

```
$objmethref =  $my_obj->can("methname") && sub { $my_obj->methname(@_) };

# then later
$objmethref->(@args);
```

but I’m not sure what it is you really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$my_obj->$methodref->(@args)
```

is

```
( $my_obj->$methodref() )->(@args)
```

In other words, it would call the method with no args, and attempt to use the result as a function reference. It's not what you want at all

The obvious means of calling it is

```
$methodref->($my_obj, @args)
```

but Perl provides a syntax that looks like a method-call for your pleasure.

```
$my_obj->$methodref(@args)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$methodref->(@args)` is a function call, not a method call, so won't have the object automatically passed.

`$my_obj->$methodref->(@args)` would call $methodref with no parameters other than the object parameter, and use its return value as a coderef, calling that and passing it the indicated args.